# 'Cannot refer to a non-final variable result inside an inner class defined in a different method'

Tags: android

I am new to android development so please bear with me. I have recently been following some dialog box tutorials and realised how verbose it is to create a dialog box and display it to the user. So I have placed all the relevant dialog box code into a handy static method. See below:

```
public static boolean dialog(Context context, String text)
{
    boolean result = false;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(text);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                result = true;}
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                result = false;}
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return result;
}
```

However when the compiler does not like the lines `result = true` or `result = false`. It returns the error `Cannot refer to a non-final variable result inside an inner class defined in a different method`.

I have searched for a solution to this answer, but all the answers I have either not understood properly or they have not been a proper solution to my problem (eg, I cannot just make the variable 'final').

Any suggestions for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to move result in the class scope

Comment: Btw, your method will always return "false". Why do you want to return a boolean?

Comment: What makes you think it will always return false? The `result = true` and `result = false` declarations are inside their respective yes/no `onClick` events. I believe this is correct, have I written the code incorrectly?

Comment: Because you are creating a dialog and returning the result immediately. This result will only change the second time if you pressed "Yes".

Comment: Oh so the code does not pause at `dialog.show();`? Ah, I see the problem now, thanks. I am used to coding in `C#` and finding alot of differences.

Comment: My intention was to create an easy static method that could be used to show a dialog box and return a boolean depending on which option the user picked. Is that possible in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ken Wolf`s answer is **NOT** a solution. Dont you know, that **dialog(...)** will return **result** before you can touch Dialog button? Its Java basics. You need to do something in onClick, something like calling **getActivity().onDialogYesButton()** and **getActivity().onDialogNoButton()**!

Answer (score 0):

Declare `result` outside your method.

```
static boolean result = false;

public static boolean dialog(Context context, String text) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(text);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There might be - can't you just execute whatever method you need in the `onClicks` instead of returning a boolean and using that somewhere else?

Comment: I was hoping for a re-usable dialog method though, hence why I've tried to put my contextual logic outside of the scope of this method. I guess I could put my logic inside the scope of this method, but then I would no longer have a nice re-usable method to call when I needed a yes/no dialog box. My only known alternative is to write this horribly verbose dialog code every time I need it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid side-effects with closures in java `local` variables referenced by an anonymous delegate must be marked as `final`. You can make that a *class/static* variable.

Comment: I can't make this variable final, it needs to be modified at a later point. But making the variable a class variable has worked perfectly - albeit a bit of a messy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own callback interface somewhere

```
public interface DialogResult {
    void onDialogResult(boolean result);
}
```

then pass that down to the dialog

```
public static void dialog(Context context, String text, final DialogResult callback) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(text);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                callback.onDialogResult(true);
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                callback.onDialogResult(false);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

and the dialog will at some point in the future use the callback to notify you of the result. You can't just return a result from the future.

Then simply use it like all those other callbacks

```
static class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ....
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
        b.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // show dialog at some point
            dialog(v.getContext(), "Hello Dialog", mDialogCallback);
        }
    };

    private DialogResult mDialogCallback = new DialogResult() {
        @Override
        public void onDialogResult(boolean result) {
            // do something with the result
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `You can't just return a result from the future.` < I know that, I was just not aware how java operates. In the past I have done a lot of coding in C#, where calling a dialog box will pause the rest of the code. I have learnt now that java operates very differently :)

Answer (score -1):

A local class can only access local variables that are declared final.